# tamanho de imagens em kb para upload

Tags: android, imagem

estou fazendo uma aplicacao para android, e tenho que trabalhar com download e upload de fotos...
ja estou redimencionando as fotos maiores que 1000x1000px para este mesmo tamanho... 
e usando o metodo

```
yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);
```

para diminuir o tamanho da imagem em KB para facilitar o upload e download...

meu problema é q algumas imagens passam de 3mb e usando o compress como acima, elas ficam perto de 500kb, e teria q passar mais uma vez no compress para ficarem menor

mas ao mesmo tempo existem imagens de 50kb que ao passar no compress ficam com 8kb ou seja nao precisaria do compress...

entao eu preciso de um metodo que retorne o tamanho da imagem em kb ou mb tanto faz... ai conseguiria tratar este meu problema...

agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Método `length()` :

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileSizeExample 
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   File file =new File("sua_imagem.ext");
        if(file.exists())
        {    double bytes = file.length();
             double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
             double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
             System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
             System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);
             System.out.println("megabytes : " + megabytes);
        }else
        {    System.out.println("Arquivo nem existe!");
        }

    }
}
```

[Fonte](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-file-size-in-java/)